# How can i protect audio file and play in my react native app?

Tags: javascript, node.js, react-native, express, encryption

I need to protect my audio file from other media-player apps.
So how to encrypt the audio file and decrypt it for play on my react native app.
back-end is nodeJs with expressJs.

Answer (score 2):

You can use an NPM package like cryptify or file-encryptor.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/cryptify

https://www.npmjs.com/package/file-encryptor

Thanks.